# Calendar with events for DJANGO

Tags: ajax, json, django, calendar, fullcalendar

Can anyone clarify my doubts please. I need to add a calendar with events in my djnago app.
It should show events taken from Database and also dynamically keep on adding events.

I have searched a lot on web, and I came across FULLCALENDAR. Currently I am facing some API issues.

But, I would like to know is the fullcalendar displaying calendar widget  only FULL screen?
Can we make it small like datepicker ??

Also, I came across django-agenda, django-schedule, HTMLCalendar,dhtmlschedular.
But, I am not getting its classes, methods, or coding examples.

If you know any websites, links, tutorials ... please please comment and suggest !

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/sandlbn/django-bootstrap-calendar

Comment: No. I have not tried it. But,  can I make the calendar small in size? Also, any documentation link for it, if you know would be helpful. Thanks !!

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/

Comment: Well ! I am late to reply ! Apologies! But, things are still not working well ! I am now trying to make a custom calendar ! I hope it works ! Thanks for help !